# [CLIPS][JAVA]How to acquire string from console and insert inputs

Tags: java, string, clips, expert-system

I'm developing a little expert-system with Clips and Java using Clipsjni.
I've encountered a problem and I can't find a solution online, so I'm asking to You.
I want to put the output of the function clips.run() in a JLable becouse I need to use java swing and I want to put the input from a TextBox and not from the console.

Here's an example of a program that runs normally with the console:

```
import net.sf.clipsrules.jni.Environment;

public class Example {

    public static Environment clips = new Environment();
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        clips.load("hello.clp");
        clips.reset();
        clips.run();
    }
}
```

And this is my Hello.clp:

```
(defrule question
=>
(printout t "How old are you?" crlf)
(assert (age (read)))
)
```

this is what i get from the system console:

> How old are you?
>   12

So I want " How old are you? " to be saved in a String type and put the "12" from a string. How can I solve this? 
Hoping for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than placing strings that will be seen by the user directly within the rules, use facts instead.

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate question
  (slot id)
  (slot text))
CLIPS>   
(deftemplate value
  (slot id)
  (slot value))
CLIPS>   
(defrule ask-question
  (question (id ?id)
            (text ?text))
  =>
  (printout t ?text " ")
  (assert (value (id ?id) (value (read)))))
CLIPS> (assert (question (id age) (text "How old are you?")))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
How old are you? 44
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (question (id age) (text "How old are you?"))
f-2     (value (id age) (value 44))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (question (id age) (text "Wie alt sind Sie?")))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
Wie alt sind Sie? 44
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (question (id age) (text "Wie alt sind Sie?"))
f-2     (value (id age) (value 44))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS>
```

In CLIPSJNI, you can use the assertString function to assert facts into CLIPS from your Swing application. For example, here's a snippet from the WineDemo example included with CLIPSJNI:

```
clips.assertString("(attribute (name sauce) (value unknown))");
```

Use the fact query functions to extract information from facts. For example, here's a snippet from the SudokoDemo example included with CLIPSJNI:

```
 String evalStr;
 String messageStr = "<html><p style=\"font-size:95%\">";

 evalStr = "(find-all-facts ((?f technique)) TRUE)";

 MultifieldValue mv = (MultifieldValue) clips.eval(evalStr);
 int tNum = mv.size();

 for (int i = 1; i <= tNum; i++)
   {
    evalStr = "(find-fact ((?f technique-employed)) " +
                   "(eq ?f:priority " + i + "))";

    mv = (MultifieldValue) clips.eval(evalStr);
    if (mv.size() == 0) continue;

    FactAddressValue fv = (FactAddressValue) mv.get(0);

    messageStr = messageStr + ((NumberValue) fv.getFactSlot("priority")).intValue() + ". " +
                              ((LexemeValue) fv.getFactSlot("reason")).lexemeValue() + "<br>";
   }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jfrm,messageStr,sudokuResources.getString("SolutionTechniques"),JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Basically you use the eval function to execute the query and return a list of facts in a CLIPS multifield value. You retrieve the facts from the multifield and then use the getFactSlot function to retrieve specific slot values.

Answer (score 0):

```
   FactAddressValue fv = (FactAddressValue) ((MultifieldValue) clips.eval("(find-fact ((?f flower_name)) TRUE)")).get(0); // "flower_name"  is deftemplate name 

   String ou = fv.getFactSlot("name").toString() ; // "name" is the slot name 
    //String ou = value.toString() ; 
    System.out.println(ou) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! You have answered an old question, and your answer is the same as the existing answer. To gather more upvotes you should make clear how your answer differs from the existing answer, and write a bit about how it works. Please see [writing good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)